# How to exclude specific component from caching Using Nuxt.js keep-alive props?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have trouble with Nuxt.js keep-alive prop, I am trying to cache all components except one, and load dynamic data again.
But all components are cached, I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.
Is this the correct way to use keep-alive in Nuxt.js?

`Default layout`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{exclude: ['basket']}" />
  </div>
</template>
```

`Inside basket`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>basket</h1>
    {{items}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {       
  async fetch() {
    let resp = await this.$axios.$get('api/items')
    this.items = resp.data
   },    
  fetchOnServer:false,
}
</script>
```

Vue devtools

[image]

Comment: Can you give a `name: 'basket'` to your Basket component and see if this changes anything?

Comment: I tried but to no avail, the API is not called during routing

Comment: What? Can you please make a [repro] and explain a bit better what you want to do here? It's not clear and we're missing info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keep-alive` only caches page components, so I'm assuming `basket` is a page.

The component name for pages is the relative path to the page. Assuming this directory structure:

```
pages/
 - index.vue
 - basket.vue
```

...the name for the `basket` page would be `"pages/basket.vue"`:

```html
<Nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{exclude: ['pages/basket.vue']}" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-keep-page-alive-ahq42s?file=layouts%2Fdefault.vue)

Comment: [The Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#keep-alive) suggests that you can exclude non-page components too. `:keep-alive-props="{ exclude: ['modal'] }"`, `modal` is obviously not a page component.